# Trying to Bucket Days in Dax but getting an error message - The MAX function only accepts a column reference as the argument number 1

Tags: powerbi, max, dax

this is the measure i came up with, I'm completely new to DAX

Cancellation buckets = CALCULATE(IF(MAX([# Cancellations]) <=1 , "current",
IF( MAX([# Cancellations]) > 1 && MAX([# Cancellations])<30, "1-30 Days",
IF(MAX([#  Cancellations])>= 30 && MAX([#  Cancellations]) < 60, "31-60 Days", BLANK()))))

the cancellations with success plans is a measure and its set to number. what am I doing wrong here?

[PLEASE HELP]: [VAR Formula but how do I eliminate calculating blanks here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPYIG.png)

Comment: DAX measure returns a number. Then, you are trying to take MAX of that number, which makes no sense. To fix this, simply use your measure without MAX. Also, you should save your measure in a variable and instead of multiple IFs use SWITCH function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Cancellation buckets =
VAR Cancellations = [# SBC Cancellations With Success Plan Days]
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        ISBLANK ( Cancellations ), BLANK (),
        Cancellations <= 1, "current",
        Cancellations < 30, "1-30 Days",
        Cancellations < 60, "31-60 Days"
    )
```

Comment: VAR Cancellations = [# SBC Cancellations With Success Plan Days]
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        [# SBC Cancellations With Success Plan Days] <= 30, "0-30 Days",
        [# SBC Cancellations With Success Plan Days] <= 60, "30-60 Days",
        [# SBC Cancellations With Success Plan Days] <= 90, "61-90 Days"
    )  tried this but getting an error message still, also when doing this how can I make sure that if the #SBC Cancellations is a blank the new VAR Cancellation Measure also returns a blank, rather than Variance?  Many thanks for your help in advance @RADO

Comment: You are getting this error because you changed my formula and introduced a problem - Power BI perceives VAR Cancellations as a measure name, which is wrong. Please use my code exactly as it is.

Comment: Cancellation buckets = 
VAR Cancellations = [# SBC Cancellations With Success Plan Days]
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        Cancellations <= 30, "Cancelled <30 Days",
        Cancellations <- 60, "Cancelled 31-60 Days",
        Cancellations <= 90, "Cancelled 61-90 Days",
        Cancellations > 90, "Cancelled 90+")

Above is working now, but I have one more question - how do I eliminate the blanks from this, normally in excel I'd use IF(ISBLANK)," ") but how does that work in DAX in this example? Basically to filter only to Calculate/show values if #SBC measure has a value

Comment: It works the same way in DAX. I have updated the formula.

Comment: could you please check my other question, which is in relation to this one? Would much appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is partially correct just remove the `Calculate` function.

`Measure 5 = IF(MAX('Table'[# SBC Cancellations With Success Plan Days]) <=1, "Current", IF(MAX('Table'[# SBC Cancellations With Success Plan Days]) > 1 && MAX('Table'[# SBC Cancellations With Success Plan Days]) < 30, "1-30 days", IF(MAX('Table'[# SBC Cancellations With Success Plan Days]) >=30 && MAX('Table'[# SBC Cancellations With Success Plan Days]) < 60, "31-60 days", BLANK())))`

Check the above formula, accept if it helps, thank you:)

Note:- Make sure to check the `Show items with no data` option.

[image: Show items with no data]

Comment: Bare in mind the #SBC Cancellations is a measure and not a part of the table, so that does not solve the issue.  Any other ideas please?